# Make DataGrid cells readonly

Tags: .net, windows, winforms, datagrid, compact-framework

There is DataGrid (WinForms / .NET CF 3.5) bounded with DataSource to list object.
How to disable data editing in cells?

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
dt.Columns(0).ReadOnly = True '// Make the column(0) readonly and assign to DataGrid.

dataGridView1.DataSource = dt
```

This code can make any column you set as read only. By the way,

> dt

represents as datatable that is used to gather data from database and its datasource to the datagrid dataGridView1.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using DataGridView instead of DataGrid and set it's EditMode property to EditProgrammatically

```
  dataGridView1.EditMode = DataGridViewEditMode.EditProgrammatically;
```